# R.id not found when writing Espresso test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I tried writing a small test to try Espresso.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.somemodule

import com.mycompany.myapp.R
import other.uselful.imports

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class DemoTest {

    @get:Rule
    var startActivity: ActivityTestRule<StartActivity> = ActivityTestRule(StartActivity::class.java)


    @Test
    fun aDemoTest() {
        onView(withId(R.id.theElementId))
                .check(matches(isClickable()))
    }
}
```

Android Studio doesn't show any error. if I ctrl+click on `R.id.theElementID`, it finds it in the appropriate layout file. However when I try to run, I get a compile error:

> Unresolved reference: id

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this issue. Spent 4 hours investigating, and no luck finding anything useful on the internet.

So, I'm hoping that the information below may help someone.

Short answer:

1. clean the project
2. execute `gradlew :app:build` from the command line / Terminal, it may show a build error which leads to the root cause

The longer answer:

I did the following:

1. I hit "Invalidate caches and restart" from Android Studio
2. I've executed `gradlew :app:build` from the command line

The second step printed an error message that the BuildConfig was duplicated.
The reason for this issue was, that I had 2 modules (android-app and android-library) with slightly different package names (I made a typo when creating the second one). This led to the failed build from the command line. After modifying the 2nd module's package name to be the same as the 1st one, the issue was solved.

I didn't receive the "R.id not found" error. So, I could continue to write the UI tests, which worked :-)

Happy coding!

Comment: "execute gradlew :app:build from the command line / Terminal, it may show a build error which leads to the root cause" - this helped me find the cause! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** Try remove any incorrect `import android.R` statement.

**Long answer**
I also have faced this issue.

In my case, in test class, I was importing `android.R` package due to referring some incorrect resource id previously (`R.id.progress`) which belonged to `android.R` package.

I removed that reference as well ans the import statement i.e. `import android.R` from the test class and the issue resolved. Then source recognized the `R.id.etPassword` resource id of my layout file.

Answer (score 0):

guess the actual problem is, that the activity had not been started.

`R.id.theElementId` might be an invalid resource descriptor.

try `R.id.the_element_id` instead.

Comment: camel case ids works everywhere else. I don't think this is the issue. The UiThreadTest tag didn't help. thanks anyway

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud the error message is quite limited, in order to get a reliable understanding of the actual cause. without `@UiThreadTest` annotation, there won't be any views accessible. access through `kotlinx.android.synthetic.` might be another option.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed, that's the only message I get, with the line number where R.id is called. About the @UiThreadTest annotation, I looked into it and it is not needed when using the espresso framework. Good to know